# Undefined error when clicking Publish in Experience Editor

Tags: experience-editor, pipelines, javascript

When we click the Publish button in the Experience Editor, we receive the following error in the ExperienceEditor.js:

> "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined

The particular line (911) is "if (pipeline.get("isPipelineReady"))". In this instance, the pipeline variable is undefined. As I walk back through the call stack in Chrome Dev Tools, objects seem to be populating (for instance, 531 objects are returned from an ajax call that models whether items are in their final state or not).

The call just before this comes from Publish.js, line 40. That call tries to pass the PublishPipeline in from "context.app". That PublishPipeline property is undefined. Lots of things are defined on context.app, but I'm not sure how or when PublishPipeline is supposed to get defined.

Debugging from our Visual Studio project never sees the error, so it's client-side only.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

We were able to track down the issue. It had to do with a pipeline patch in the mvc.getRenderer pipeline--we were patching in before "Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.GetRenderer.GetViewRenderer, Sitecore.Mvc".

Removing our patch config file resolved the issue.